# JS variables to same php file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I'm extracting lat with jQuery on change when I choose a file

```
    document.getElementById("input-group").onchange = function(e)

    var liamlat = dec[1];
```

Then i'm sending it to the same php file using JSON

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify(liamlat);

        $.ajax({
           url: 'addnew.php',
           data: {lat: dataString},
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(response) {
              alert('lat added');
           }
        });
```

IN PHP I'm sending liamlat to mysql using btn_submit which is my button when i click 
"Submit"

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';


if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){



$username = $_POST['userName'];
$watervisibility = $_POST ['waterVisibility'];
$divinglocation = $_POST['divingLocation'];
$glat = json_decode($_POST['lat']);
```

And in my HTML i use a hidden form to echo it out

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="latform" placeholder="Lat" value="<?php echo $glat->var; ?>" />
```

Now i want the data from liamlat to be inserted in to my db.

The data doesn't go through and I get a response saying:

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'lat' cannot be null' in

I don't know why the data doesn't go through the json and into the form?

Answer (score 0):

Please add more data to post data in ajax function;

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'addnew.php',
       data: {
            lat: dataString,
            btn_submit: 1,
            userName: 'username',
            waterVisibility: 'waterVisibility',
            divingLocation: 'divingLocation'
        },
       type: 'POST',
       success: function(response) {
          alert('lat added');
       }
});
```

And please read document about ajax first.:

https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for that. I had to go for a different approach though.